# Excel - Calculating count from one sheet and pasting in another sheet in same Workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have an Excel Worksheet that has 2 sheets. Sheet 1 and Sheet 2.

Sheet 1 has the following info with samples being 1 or 0. This sheet is then filtered where Column D (Sample) is 1.

**Sheet 1:**

```
---------------------------------------------
|Column A|Column B  |Column C   |Column D   |
---------------------------------------------
|  ID   |   NAME    |   TYPE    |    SAMPLE |
---------------------------------------------
|  A012 |Brad Pitt  |   Agent   |   1       |
---------------------------------------------
|  A013 |Brad Pitt  |   Agent   |   0       |
---------------------------------------------
|  A014 |Brad Pitt  |   Agent   |   1       |
---------------------------------------------
|  A015 |Brad Pitt  |   Agent   |   1       |
---------------------------------------------
|  A016 |Brad Pitt  |   Agent   |   0       |
---------------------------------------------
|  A017 |Brad Pitt  |   Agent   |   1       |
---------------------------------------------
|  A018 |Brad Pitt  |   Agent   |   0       |
---------------------------------------------
|  A019 |Brad Pitt  |   Agent   |   0       |
---------------------------------------------
|  A020 |Brad Pitt  |   Agent   |   1       |
---------------------------------------------
|  A021 |Brad Pitt  |   Agent   |   1       |
---------------------------------------------
|  A022 |Brad Pitt  |   Agent   |   0       |
---------------------------------------------
|  A023 |Brad Pitt  |   Agent   |   1       |
---------------------------------------------
|  A024 |Angie Jolie    |   Agent   |   1   |
---------------------------------------------
|  A024 |Angie Jolie    |   Agent   |   0    |
---------------------------------------------
|  A024 |Angie Jolie    |   Agent   |   1    |
---------------------------------------------
|  A024 |Angie Jolie    |   Agent   |   0   |
---------------------------------------------
|  A024 |Angie Jolie    |   Agent   |   1   |
---------------------------------------------
|  A024 |Angie Jolie    |   Agent   |   1   |
----------------------------------------------
```

Sheet 2 has info where Column B should take the distinct name from Column B (Name) from Sheet 1 and then COUNT the number of Samples (which had been filtered earlier to show only 1s) and put that count in Column C in that same row of the name of that person (In sheet 2)

**Sheet 2:**

```
|Column A|Column B  |Column C   |Column D       |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  Line |   NAME    |   Count   |  Description  |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  1    |Brad Pitt  |       7   |Blah blah blah |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  2    |Angie Jolie|       4   |Blah blah blah |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm sure this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Formula for `C2` of `Sheet2` is:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!B:B, B2, Sheet1!D:D, 1)
```

You can copy/paste it all the way in your column `C` of `Sheet2`.